# UI in wxpython corners

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

Right now, I am using wxpython to make a UI. But I find out that under windows invironment, the four corners are all angles. 
[image]

Is it possible to change the form of the four corners and make them more smooth like this?

[image]

Comment: @Mike Driscoll As an expert in wxpython, can you help me to assess these two problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

WxPython is based on WxWidgets and, as you can see on [WxWidget's homepage](http://www.wxwidgets.org/):

> Unlike other cross-platform toolkits, wxWidgets gives its applications a truly native look and feel because it uses the platform's native API rather than emulating the GUI

Basically this means that WxWidgets and, by extension, WxPython are great choices if you want to design cross platform GUIs that automatically conform to each platform's GUI style. The downside of this is that it is not the best choice of toolkits if you want to make custom GUI elements, like those rounded corners.

I'm not too familiar with Tkinter (another popular Python GUI toolkit) but [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892521/tkinter-custom-window) seems to be exactly what you want. Perhaps you should experiment using Tkinnter instead of WxPython.

**----EDIT----**
It turns out I was wrong. There **IS** a way to do it in WxPython, as evidenced by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087140/custom-window-frame-and-window-appearance-with-wxpython). However, I maintain that WxPython is best suited to native-style windows and if you want to make completely custom UIs then you'll find better support working with another toolkit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have seen other materials and cannot find out a perfect solution. Your answer is a good conclusion for this problem. Maybe I have to talk with my teammate about changing another library.

Comment: @ShyHU I updated my answer with some more information you may find useful.