# Custom Window Frame and Window Appearance with wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

As a quick example, the game manager Steam uses custom windows that look different from the default provided by the operating system. An example of this in a random Steam alert: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEud2.png

I would like to make a program using wxPython that has such a custom appearance. How might I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://hasenj.wordpress.com/2009/04/14/making-a-fancy-window-in-wxpython/) is a good tutorial that shows you how to make a window in your own custom design.

Answer (score 2):

wxPython uses the native widgets of the OS it's running on in most cases. Thus, it really doesn't support theming. You can do the hack that "halex" mentioned and you may be able to do it by using a transparent frame and some fancy drawing or custom widgets. Otherwise, you might want to look at a different toolkit.