# How do I create a borderless window in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, window, kivy

I am building a python desktop application using Kivy and would like to find out how to create a borderless window similar to how EVE Online does it: [EVE Online launch screen](http://cdn1.eveonline.com/www/newssystem/media/8693/1/eve_launcher_v003.jpg).

This is where I am now, and what I want to achieve in the next step: [What I want to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDqBd.png)

I've spent hours Googling for a solution, but the closest I've ever come were these links: [How can I hide the main window titlebar and place a transparent background in kivy framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613738/how-can-i-hide-the-main-window-titlebar-and-place-a-transparent-background-in-ki),  and this: [Borderless windows in wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087140/custom-window-frame-and-window-appearance-with-wxpython)

Here is the current code (Python 2.7, Kivy 1.9):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '480')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '320')
Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', '1')

class MyApp(App):
def build(self):
    button = Button(text="Exit", size_hint=(None, None))
    button.bind(on_press=exit)
    return button

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I would like to see if this can be accomplished in Kivy. Would you be able to suggest some approaches to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, you know if´s possible move the window without border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a borderless window set the Windows.borderless property to true

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (500, 300)
Window.borderless = True
```

Be sure to provide an alternative way to exit your program since you won't be able to click on window close buttons normally provided by the OS.

see [kivy.core.window documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/core/window.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the widget BoxLayout and configure the settings so it will appear as you want it to. I'm new to Kivy, but these videos explain it very well:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-NvpKDReKyg hopefully this helps a bit!

Answer (score 0):

You could add Config.set ('graphics', 'resizable', '0') which removes the remaining border part of the window. The drawback is that the window is not draggable anymore and stays on a fixed position.