# How to Change the Title Font Size and Logo Size For the Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

Have couple of queries.

a. In order to set any title we use the following below command

```
master.title("Hello Welcome To Python World")
```

But then how can I change the Title Text Font Size??

b. Was able to add a logo to the title window with the below command

```
img_tmp="pylogo.jpg"
img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img_tmp))
root.call('wm','iconphoto',root,img)
```

But then how can I change the size of the logo image that gets loaded onto the frame ??

Kindly drop in your comments/suggestions/temporary code snipet for the same.

Thanks in Advance ! 
Regards,
Vimo

Answer (score 2):

The following code will only change the Font.

```
import tkinter as tk
 
root = tk.Tk()
root.option_add('*Font', '19')
root.geometry("200x150")
 
label = tk.Label(root, text = "Hello World")
label.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
 
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Tkinter is really limited, you'd have to use some other kind of window manager import or some sort; I did try this a while back, however with tkinter alone - it is impossible.

- Theoretically you can, however, archieve this by making a [custom window.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892521/tkinter-custom-window)
- Or creating a [custom title bar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter/48738216#48738216)